# Adding git Submodule error for installing RestKit

Tags: iphone, ios, git, restkit

I want to install the RestKit for my project but in the first step when I want to add git submodule by using Terminal it gives me this error:

```
command not found
```

Here is the code that I input:

```
$ cd /path/to/MyApplication

$ git init
$ git submodule add git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git
$ open RestKit
```

The first line of code works but when I input the second line it gives me the error, anybody can help me please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest versions of XCode4 the command line tools (like git) are not installed by default. If you go to the Preferences menu you can install the command line utilities from there. You may need to restart your terminal after they've installed.

Answer (score 0):

You should install **git** first for your OS.

like `apt-get install git` in ubuntu
or `brew install git` in OSX